# why my imageview is shrinking while im scrolling my tabelview cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Im dynamically resizing my label, which is in my tabelview cell.the number of cells appearing in a view its fine.but while im scrolling that new cells are having big size of image view.please let me know.why?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

   TVcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if (cell == nil)
   cell = [[TVcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   cell.titleLabel.text = [[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"title"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
   cell.txtlabel.text = [[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
   cell.IMGLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   [cell.IMGLabel sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[enclosureUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
    [cell.IMGLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.IMGLabel.layer setCornerRadius:2.5f];
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath: never returns nil, so delete

   `if (cell == nil)
   cell = [[TVcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`
2. note, setCornerRadius inside UITableViewCell will make scrolling not smooth. Better prepare image with rounded corners using Core Graphics.
3. `[cell setNeedsLayout];` - UITableviewCell will layout cell view automatically, so it's excess.
4. If you use Self Sizing Cell you should set in ViewDidLoad:

   `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0;
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

Comment: still im getting same issue

Comment: Did you use Self Sizing Cell?

Comment: as I understand, you want cell change height depend on image height?

Comment: if yes, you need to create an outlet of height constraint of imageView and change it in the code depend on height of image

Answer (score 0):

These is happening because you should clear previous data from cell before you can reuse it.

In `TVcell`class you should override method `prepareForReuse`and set all data in your labels and image view to nil.

Comment: sd_setImageWithURL does it automatically for image. Labels sets before layout. So, not needed clearing data manually.